# C# Compiler incorrect async, await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am not asking a question but discussion about bug/mistake in C# Compiler.

```
// do a heavy job it take 2s and return "1"
public async Task<string> DoJob() {
    var task = new Task<string>(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return "1";
    });
    task.Start();
    return await task;
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var task= DoJob();
    textBox1.Text += await task;
    this.Text += "2";
}
```

When I click on button1 3 times I expect:

```
textBox1.Text == "111" 
this.Text == "222"
```

but results are:

```
textBox1.Text == "1" 
this.Text == "222"
```

**And another bug**, while waiting for 2s (before 2s) I change textBox1.Text by input keyboard but result still same "1" instead of append to the end of text (+= operator).

---

Base on my knowledge async and await are keywords do nothing but help compiler know where to put code into block (correct me):

**Example**

**input**:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var task= DoJob();

    textBox1.Text += await task;
    this.Text += "2";
}
```

**output**: this give result as I expect but different with C# Compiler do. And this also don't have **And another bug** above.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var task= DoJob();

    task.ContinueWith((_task) => {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => {
            textBox1.Text += _task.Result;
            this.Text += "2";
        }));
    });
}
```

but MS C# Compiler do something like that:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var task = DoJob();

    var left = textBox1.Text;
    task.ContinueWith((_task) => {                // textBox1.Text += await task;
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => {            //
            textBox1.Text = left + _task.Result;  // 
            this.Text += "2";                     // this.Text += "2";
        }));
    });

}
```

**Do you think that is bug or Microsoft intentionally do it?**

Comment: There is no bug here

Comment: @TheGeneral There is, but it's in the OP's code, not the compiler.  This is a classic race condition.  The best solution would be to disable the button until the method is done updating the UI to avoid it.

Comment: @juharr ahh yeah, no compiler bug

Comment: [The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

Comment: @RuudHelderman and its so true

Comment: yes it is not bug, may be they make mistake in first place and publish release version so they can't change it. Changing it will affect many project. You can't ensure that in the first place.

Comment: No it's not a bug, it's the way the compiler works and should work, it can't guess what you want and nor should it try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some languages, such as C++, allow the compiler to choose what order expressions are evaluated within a given statement.  But C# eliminates this ambiguity: evaluation is always from left to right.

```
textBox1.Text += await task;
```

In C#, there is no special += operator, it just expands to:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + await task;
```

Now if we evaluate from left to right, the first thing it should evaluate is textBox1.set_Text for assignment.  If you were to do something on the right hand side that would change the value of textBox1, you would still end up assigning to the original textBox1, not the new value.

The next thing to evaluate is textBox1.get_Text.  This should return your value of "".

Then it evaluates the "await task".  At this point, it gets stuck waiting and cannot continue evaluation of the statement, so it dumps the important contents of the current stack frame into a heap object for later use.  When it comes back to continue evaluation, we now have the following information evaluated:

1. The address of the object we're going to write to.
2. The string value "".
3. The string value "1".

All that's left to do is add the captured "" to awaited "1" and assign that to the captured textBox1.

If you do that multiple times in quick succession, all 3 inputs will be the same each time.  In other words, it's behaving exactly as it should be as described by the standard.  The suggestions people are giving to put it on the previous line like this:

```
var temp = await task;
textBox1.Text += temp;
```

That is simply moving the await before the textBox1.Text.  You could actually do the re-ordering inline and give the expected results, simply by reversing the order of expressions within the statement:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Concat(
    new[] { await task, textBox1.Text }.Reverse());
```

Comment: I expected your answer. Thank for "textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + await task;" how can I forget this? 
textBox1.setText(textBox1.getText() + await task);

Answer (score 4):

Consider these two paths:

```
textBox1.Text += await task;
```

vs.

```
string newText = await task;
textBox1.Text += newText;
```

In the first example, the current value of textBox1.Text is **read** first immediately by all three clicks, which is presumably just the original empty text box value.
Then, as each one finishes, it *writes* the original value (as it was when it was read, which, reminder is still the empty string) plus the "1" that you want to concatenate.  So if you click the button quickly, all three threads *write* the value of "" + "1"

In the second example, you await getting the result text that you want to concatenate, then (on the UI thread) you perform the += operation which will read, concat and write without interruption.

If you await in the += then the original value is read before you start awaiting and the resulting concatenation is applied to the value saved in the context of the await.

Does that make sense now?

Comment: You say same as TheGeneral. why do they have to read before and not after? They take the same cost. If they read and modified after confusing will disappear and 2 of your code will do the same thing. They exactly same in other stories but not in this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no compiler bug here. However, This line is your problem

```
textBox1.Text += await task;
```

if you changed the following, you would find consistent results.

```
var result = await task;
textBox1.Text += result;
```

A simple analogy is you are asking someone for a results (a word or number for instance), and when you have finished doing your own work you want to add your results to theirs. The problem arises when you do this several time really fast. You got their original value 3 times (you are saying, give me what you have, give me what you have, give me what you have), your are going off to do your 3 separate works, when you come back you just add it to the original value (the unmodified value), which seems like it is effectively overwriting the value and not working.

Comment: LOL.  I posted my answer and then read this (which you must have posted while I was writing mine) and thought "how did my post get edited so quickly?"  All I can say is, it must be true.  ;)

Comment: I get your point, but the last sentence "it is effectively overwriting the value and not working". 3 task actually ran and take resource, cpu.